# Configurar angular com servidor php

Tags: php, angularjs

preciso configurar o angular para mandar dados para o php?

Percebi que no arquivo:
C:\wamp\www\angular\bower_components\angular\angular.js

tem configurações de servidor, métodos, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor forma de comunicar-se com servidores back-end (tua aplicação PHP) utilizando o AngularJS é utilizando o $http.

Você podia dar uma estudada melhor em AngularJS, e RESTful.

Para AngularJS estude fazendo o curso do [Codeschool](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js), para RESTful procure frameworks em PHP que abstraiam o trabalho pesado de implementação.

Boa sorte!!

Comment: Caso te ajude, eu dei uma pequena explicação nesse post: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85570/como-persistir-um-registro-no-banco-de-dados-atrav%C3%A9s-de-webservice-restful-java/85594#85594 de como configurar uma aplicação utilizando AngularJS

Answer (score 2):

Você pode mandar os dados para o php utilizando $http.post ou $http.get.

```
    .controller('BuscaCtrl',function($scope,$http) {
            // Faz a busca no php
            $http.get('<caminho do arquivo .php>')
            .success(function(data){
                    // Pega os dados recebidos do php
                    console.log(data);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Permita-me mais algumas perguntas.

Onde insiro esta linha? .controller('BuscaCtrl',function($scope,$http) {

O BuscaCtrl é alguma função?

$http.get('<caminho do arquivo .php>') //Seria o controller do cakephp? Caso sim, qual a forma de passar a função ou action para buscar no banco?

Comment: André, recomendo ler alguns tutoriais da internet sobre como implementar o angularjs. Em brase, esse código que te passei ficaria em um arquivo .js ou até mesmo dentro das tags <script></script> da sua página com os parametros que o angular necessita para executar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar também o angular-resource ($resource) é um arquivo separado do angular.js, ele faz o que o $http faz de uma forma mais elegante!

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Eu acho que a resposta está na fronteira entre "só-link" e "resposta-pobre-porém-válida". Não vou votar e deixo aos demais, lembrando que a regra é *"se não tivesse nenhum link, a resposta se sustentaria?"*