# Como persistir um registro no banco de dados através de webservice restful Java?

Tags: java, web-service, java-ee, netbeans, restful

Já possuo um método que recebe um json e persiste no banco de dados Mysql. Consigo testá-lo pela interface criada pelo Netbeans, cujo qual possui um campo para a inserção de um json, porém, como faço para, dentro de uma aplicação java, fazer uma requisição http passando o json como parâmetro para ser persistido?

**Método utilizado para a persistência de dados:**

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
public void putJson(String json) throws Exception{
    Cliente cliente;
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    java.lang.reflect.Type tipo = new TypeToken<Cliente>(){}.getType();

    cliente = gson.fromJson(json, tipo);

    Conexao con = new Conexao();
    con.conexao();

    PreparedStatement ps = con.con.prepareStatement("insert into cliente values(?,?)");
    ps.setString(1, cliente.getCnpj());
    ps.setString(2, cliente.getRazao_social());
    ps.execute();

}
```

Desde já obrigado!

Comment: Marco, te aconselho a usar o $http do AngularJS pra isso é super simples e rápido de fazer, se tiver interesse posto um código aqui pra vc ;)

Comment: Opa, por favor Fábio!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te aconselho a usar AngularJS, é muito prático e de fácil aprendizado, fiz um exemplo para você no [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fabiohbarbosa/u2vy57d6/13/).

Nesse exemplo mostrei como consumir uma API REST pelo método GET, sei que você precisa de um POST, mas eu não encontrei um ENDPOINT POST disponível para fazer o exemplo, mas acredito que o código de um exemplo GET vai te ajudar a conceitualizar sobre angular, ai no final dou um exemplo de POST. Ok?

Aqui vai o código e suas as explicações:

**Arquivo Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('HtmlController',['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    var endpoint = 'http://162.243.233.191:3000/api/ip';
    $scope.buscarJson = function () {
        $http.get(endpoint).success(function (data) {
            $scope.json = data;
        }).error(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
    };
}]);
```

Aqui criamos nosso módulo angular chamado **myApp**, em seguida, criamos um controller que utilizaremos na nossa tela HTML chamado **HtmlController**.

O angular trabalha com controle de injeção de dependências o **$scope** e **$http** são dependências do angular que estamos injetando para usar no nosso controller.

O **$scope** é um objeto que fica disponível para ser usado no HTML, qualquer função ou variável que você criar nele você poderá usar na sua tela (desde que a tela esteja usando esse controller).

Temos a função **buscarJson**, usaremos essa função para buscar o IP do usuário, essa função utiliza o **$http** do angular e busca um IP address no **enpoint** 
http://162.243.233.191:3000/api/ip, caso obtenha sucesso salva na variável **json**, caso de erro printa a mensagem de erro no console.

**Arquivo HTML**

```
<body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="HtmlController">
            <button type="button" ng-click="buscarJson()">
                Verificar IP
            </button>
            <h4> Seu IP Address é: </h4>
            <p>
                {{json.ip}}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

No HTML incluímos o JS do angular para podermos utiliza-lo no nosso **HtmlController**.

Precisamos informar ao nosso HTML o módulo angular que criamos, fazemos isso utilizando o atributo **ng-app**, em seguida também precisamos informar no nosso HTML o nosso controller, para isso passamos no **ng-controller** o nosso **HtmlController**.

Em seguida, utilizamos a função **buscarJson** que criamos no nosso controller, passa isso adicionamos no nosso button o **ng-click**.

Por fim, o angular fica *enxergando* a variável **json** através dos marcadores **{{}}**, note que estamos exibindo o campo **ip** contido no na variável **json**. Magicamente quando a variável for preenchida (ao clicar no botão) o seu IP vai aparecer na tela.

Agora no teu caso, basta você trocar o endpoint que especificamos para seu endpoint, e trocar o **$http.get** por **$http.post**, a única diferença seria essa:

```
var cliente = {
    cnpj: 45057131000143,
    razao_social: 'Stackoverflow'
};
$http.post('/seu_end_point', cliente).success(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
}).error(function(error) {
     console.log(error);
});
```

Espero ter ajudado!!!
Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição. :-)

ps: *No JsFiddle eu não importei o arquivo JS que contém o HtmlController que criamos, pois ele já faz isso automático. Quando for fazer o exemplo não esquece de importar o js no teu HTML*.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Marco mais uma coisa, você está usando o método PUT, o correto uso do método PUT é quando for alterar um registro. Ok?

POST é para salvar novos registros.